# Rails 5 - using Pundit Scopes with Statesman state machine: structurally incompatible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, state-machine, pundit

After many years of trying to learn how to use pundit scopes in my Rails app, I have just received an insight into why I can't get it working. Apparently, Pundit can't run an SQL query where one of the query parameters is a statesman state.

The suggestion I have received is to use a different state machine. Before I do that, I'm throwing this out there to see if anyone has managed to find a way to use Pundit (with scopes) and Statesman state machine.

My setup is:

ApplicationPolicy

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

ProposalPolicy

```
class ProposalPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
     def resolve
       accum_scope = scope.where(user_id: @user.id)
  #     # Depends on moving off statesman
  #     # accum_scope = accum_scope.or(accum_scope.reviewable) if @user.has_role?(:research_management, Organisation.first)
       accum_scope
     end
  end


  # I think index isnt necessary when I have a Scope
  # def index?
  #   true
  # end

  def new?
   true 
  end

  def create?
    new?
  end

  def show?
    #if its in the index results for that user
    true
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def update?
    true if record.try(:user) == user
  end

  def destroy?
    true if record.try(:user) == user
  end

  def draft?
    create?
  end

  def under_review?
    true if record.try(:user) == user
  end

  def approved?
    @user.has_role?(:research_management, Organisation.matching) 
  end

  def not_approved?
    approved?
  end

  def publish_openly?
    true if record.try(:user) == user && record.can_transition_to?(:publish_openly)
  end

  def publish_to_invitees?
    true if record.try(:user) == user && record.can_transition_to?(:publish_to_invitees)
  end

  def publish_counterparties_only?
    true if record.try(:user) == user && record.can_transition_to?(:publish_counterparties_only)
  end

  def remove?
    true if record.try(:user) == user #|| @user.has_role? :admin
  end

  private

  def matching
    @user.organisation_id == record.user.organisation_id
  end
end
```

Proposal.rb

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries

has_many :proposal_transitions, class_name: "ProposalTransition", autosave: false
scope :reviewable,  -> { in_state(:under_review) }
  def state_machine
    @state_machine ||= ProposalStateMachine.new(self, transition_class: ProposalTransition,
                                                   association_name: :proposal_transitions)
  end

  delegate :can_transition_to?, :transition_to!, :transition_to, :current_state,
           to: :state_machine


  private

  def self.transition_class
    ProposalTransition
  end

  def self.initial_state
    :draft
  end
```

The current problem:

```
 ProposalPolicy::Scope.new(User.first, Proposal).resolve.all
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organisation Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations" ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."name" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $3 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $4  [["user_id", 43], ["name", :research_management], ["resource_type", "Organisation"], ["resource_id", 5]]
  Proposal Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "proposals".* FROM "proposals" WHERE "proposals"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 43]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Proposal id: 17, user_id: 43, title: "asdf", description: "adsf", byline: "asdf", nda_required: true, created_at: "2016-11-16 00:28:31", updated_at: "2016-11-28 01:16:47", trl_id: 1, invitee_id: nil>]> 
2.3.1p112 :012 > Proposal.where(user_id: User.first).or(Proposal.reviewable)
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]
```

The insight I've just received is that the pundit scope cannot query the proposal state because statesman has a series of tables behind the scenes that manage the transitions.

Does anyone see a work around that would let me continue using statesman as well as using Pundit scopes?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer yet - I'm still trying to figure out how to do this - but I found help here: https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/440. The help explains the following:

Pundit scopes doesn't do anything special. When reading Pundit scopes, just mentally replace the scope keyword with the class name and try to type exactly the same thing into your Rails console.

The error isn't specific to Pundit. It's an error related to the or operator. I took a peek at how statesman implements the in_state call, and it does a join with your ProposalTransition class.

ActiveRecord's or operator requires the left side and the right side to be compatible. In your case, your left-side query (Proposal.where(user: User.first)) is incompatible with your right-side query:

Proposal.reviewable which translates to Proposal.in_state(:under_review) which translates to Proposal.joins(most_recent_transition_join).where(states_where(most_recent_transition_alias, states), :under_review) which does a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the transition table (proposal_transitions, I believe) [1]

To make them compatible, you'd have to apply the same join to both sides of the or.

Since you're already making an expensive call anyway, you could do a poor man's or by doing the following:

def resolve proposal_ids = current_user.proposal_ids + Proposal.reviewable.pluck(:id) Proposal.where(id: proposal_ids) end [1] I looked at statesman's source code: https://github.com/gocardless/statesman/blob/77958f1c2ae613ac29c6db5329c67538a5655ddf/lib/statesman/adapters/active_record_queries.rb